# Customize link generation in Razor Page by convention

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app that uses Razor Pages with the following route convention: `{tenantId}/{Page}`.
This is setup via the following Folder Route Model Convention:

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(opt =>
{
    opt.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", opt =>
    {
        foreach (var selector in opt.Selectors)
        {
            selector.routeModel.Template = "{tenantId}/" + selector.routeModel.Template;
        }
    });
});
```

Now comes the next problem: generating links.

For example, in the Razor Page View of one of my pages, I have the following snippet:

```
<a asp-page="/PageA">Page A</a>
```

This of course now doesn't generate the proper link anymore, because the tenantId parameter is missing.
To solve this I can do the following:

```
@{
    var tenantId = RetrieveTenantId();
}
<a asp-page="/PageA" asp-route-tenantId=@tenantId>Page A</a>
```

This is however quite a lot of overhead, because I would need to do this for every link.

Does ASP.NET Core have any system to automatically inject the tenantId prefix in every link it generates? Or to automatically provide the tenantId route value?
Any Filters or Conventions that I can configure to accomplish this?

Comment: Your Startup setting is not correct in my project.What is your version of asp.net core?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3.1. I had a small typo, which I just fixed. I’m not at my computer for a couple of days, so I can’t test it further.